# How do I skip to the next record on a find within a for each progress4gl?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I've been working on a code that runs a `for each` within another `for each` and a `find` inside it, and I need to skip the record found by the `find` statement if it doesn't match the second `for each`'s value, but I'm unintentionally skipping the table on the first `for each`.

```
for each <table>.
   for each <table1>.
      find <table2> where <table2>.<code> = <table1>.<code> no-lock no-error.
      if not avail <table2> 
      then next.
   end.
end.
```

Instead of skipping `<table1>` when not found, it's skipping `<table>`, Is there a way to fix this?

***Version***:

OpenEdge Release 10.2B

**Warning:**
I'm a newbie at progress

Comment: You are doing that. Skip is related to loops and iterations, not finds.

Comment: Probably there isn´t another table1, so it goes on to the remainder of the for each table loop, which is empty, so it proceeds to the next <table> record. You can prove it by putting a message after the end of for each table 1.
So we´re clear, NEXT always skips the current iteration of the closest loop (unless you tell it otherwise using named blocks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also not very clear to me what you are asking for ...

But when dealing with nested loops, it's always easier to use block-labels to control which of the loops you are next'ing. outerloop and innerloop are just arbitrary chosen names for the loops.

```
outerloop:
for each <table>:
   innerloop: 
   for each <table1>:
      find <table2> where <table2>.<code> = <table1>.<code> no-lock no-error.
      if not avail <table2> 
      then next innerloop .
   end.
end.
```

Comment: Oh, I've never seen that before, thanks dude for providing a simple and neat solution and explanation +1

Comment: Not sure how simplified your sample code was. But you can also next two FOR EACH'es into a single loop: 

`for each <table>,  for each <table1> where table1.... = table....:
      find <table2> where <table2>.<code> = <table1>.<code> no-lock no-error.
      if not avail <table2> 
      then next  .
   end.
end.`

Comment: That's useful, I'm still learning progress4gl that's why I barely know the simple stuff, thanks again for helping

Answer (score 1):

It is very unclear what you are trying to do.  But perhaps this is it:

```
for each table1 no-lock:

  find table2 no-lock where table2.code = table1.code no-error.

  if available table2 then
    do:
      /* do something that involves table2 */
    end.
   else
    do:
      /* do stuff that does not involve table2 -- in other words "skip it" */
    end.

end.
```

Comment: I'm sorry Tom, I got ahead of myself while making my question, I edited it